# Combine rows into columns in SQL Server in a particular way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to describe my problem, but I'll do my best. I'm working in SQL Server 2014. I've simplified the problem as much as I can since I'm working with sensitive info.

I currently have a query that returns the following from a table of test answers:

| test_id | question_id | is_checked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| 1 | 3 | FALSE |
| 1 | 4 | FALSE |
| 2 | 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| 2 | 3 | FALSE |
| 2 | 4 | TRUE |
| 3 | 1 | FALSE |
| 3 | 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | 3 | FALSE |
| 3 | 4 | FALSE |

Each test has only 4 yes/no questions (and this is unlikely to ever change). For each test, one or more questions can be marked yes. Above...

- test 1 has questions 1 and 2 as yes, the rest as no.
- test 2 has question 4 as yes, the rest as no.
- test 3 has all questions marked as no.

I want my results to look like this:

| test_id | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 | question_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

I tried to use `PIVOT` to no luck. Any help would be appreciated, and I'm happy to provide more info.

EDIT:

My attempt at using `PIVOT` (please forgive my likely horrible formatting):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT test_id, question_id, is_checked FROM example_table
) as sourcetable 
pivot(
    any(is_checked) 
    for question_id 
    in (question_1, question_2, question_3, question_4)
) as pivottable
```

Populating an example table based on the above:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (test_id int, question_id int, is_checked bit);

INSERT INTO example_table (test_id, question_id, is_checked)
VALUES
    ('1', '1', '1'),
    ('1', '2', '1'),
    ('1', '3', '0'),
    ('1', '4', '0'),
    ('2', '1', '0'),
    ('2', '2', '0'),
    ('2', '3', '0'),
    ('2', '4', '1'),
    ('3', '1', '0'),
    ('3', '2', '0'),
    ('3', '3', '0'),
    ('3', '4', '0');
```

Finally, my SQL Server version is SQL Server 2014. I previously put SQL Server 17 above, but have corrected it.

FINAL EDIT:

The column `is_checked` is a `bit` type in my system, but someone must have set it to output `TRUE` and `FALSE` when queried. In the answer below, I replaced `is_checked` with `CAST(is_checked AS INT)` and that worked.

Comment: *"I tried to use `PIVOT` to no luck"* include that attempt in your question. `PIVOT`, or conditional aggregation, is *exactly* what you need.

Comment: Google for "SQL pivot query" to find some immediate solutions.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `select @@version;`.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll edit my post with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (test_ID INT, question_id INT, is_checked VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @tbl (test_ID, question_id, is_checked) VALUES
(1, 1, 'TRUE'),
(1, 2, 'TRUE'),
(1, 3, 'FALSE'),
(1, 4, 'FALSE'),
(2, 1, 'FALSE'),
(2, 2, 'FALSE'),
(2, 3, 'FALSE'),
(2, 4, 'TRUE'),
(3, 1, 'FALSE'),
(3, 2, 'FALSE'),
(3, 3, 'FALSE'),
(3, 4, 'FALSE');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT  test_ID
   , MAX(IIF(question_id = 1, is_checked, '')) AS question_1
   , MAX(IIF(question_id = 2, is_checked, '')) AS question_2
   , MAX(IIF(question_id = 3, is_checked, '')) AS question_3
   , MAX(IIF(question_id = 4, is_checked, '')) AS question_4
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY test_ID
ORDER BY test_ID;
```

**Output**

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| test_ID | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 | question_4 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | TRUE       | TRUE       | FALSE      | FALSE      |
|       2 | FALSE      | FALSE      | FALSE      | TRUE       |
|       3 | FALSE      | FALSE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I get the error "Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator." So, the column "is_checked" must be a bit type, but it is set in my system to display as "true" or "false". I'll try casting that value to an int in the IIF expression. EDIT: That worked! Thanks. I'll make one more edit to my post with a clarification.